# Trying to use jquery to make content fade in when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the contents of the page to fade in when scrolling down and out when scrolling up, I used a websites instructions (https://www.superhi.com/blog/how-to-add-web-design-elements-that-fade-in-and-out-on-scroll) and tried to change it a bit to fit my project but it isn't working. I'm using Dreamweaver.

```
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="fadein.js"></script>   
<script>

$(document).on("scroll", function () {
  var pageTop = $(document).scrollTop()
  var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height()
  var tags = $(".fade")

  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var tag = tags[i]

    if ($(tag).position().top < pageBottom) {
      $(tag).addClass("visible")
    } else {
      $(tag).removeClass("visible")
    }
  }
})

</script>
```

```
<div id="content" style="margin:-8px;">
    <img src="images/n intro.jpg" style="width: 100%; margin-top:110px;" alt="intro image">
    <img class="fade" src="images/border.png" style="width:490px;  margin:40px; margin-left: 35%" alt="border line">

    <div id="mid">
    <h1  class="fade">Whether youre in it for...</h1>
    <img class="fade" src="images/photos/food&drink2.jpg" alt="picture of artistic coffee being made">  
    <p class="fade">The food and drink,</p>
    <img class="fade" src="images/photos/work2.jpg" alt="picture of laptop at a coffee table">
    <p class="fade">Getting some work done,</p>
    <img class="fade" src="images/photos/people2.jpg" alt="picture of a couples hands holding coffee">
    <p class="fade">The people,</p>
    <img class="fade" src="images/photos/book2.jpg" alt="picture of a book and coffee">
    <p class="fade">Or a good book,</p>
    <h2 class="fade">We got you covered!</h2>
    </div>

    <img class="fade" src="images/awards.png" style="display: block; margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto; width: 460px;" alt="three award icons">
    <ul>
        <li class="fade">Sustainable high quality coffee</li>
        <li class="fade">Comfortable seating</li>
        <li class="fade">A variety of table layouts to suit your needs</li>
        <li class="fade">High speed internet </li>
        <li class="fade">Charging ports provided</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

```
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

When I use this the page just displays everything normally, nothing fades or is invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code:

1. Your link to jQuery isn't pointing to actual jQuery. I looked at the tutorial, and yes that's what they use, but you need to use the CDN link:
   `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
2. `fade.js` is just the name they used for where they put the `script` that you included. you don't necessarily need that.
3. You need to add a `transition` property to the `.fade` class, other wise, you won't see it fade in or out, it will simply switch from 0 `opacity` to 1 (or full).

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
  var pageTop = $(document).scrollTop()
  var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height() - 20
  var tags = $(".fade")

  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    var tag = tags[i]

    if ($(tag).position().top < pageBottom) {
      $(tag).addClass("visible")
    } else {
      $(tag).removeClass("visible")
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.fade.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" style="margin:-8px;">
    <img src="images/n intro.jpg" style="width: 100%; margin-top:110px;" alt="intro image">
    <img class="fade" src="images/border.png" style="width:490px;  margin:40px; margin-left: 35%" alt="border line">

    <div id="mid">
    <h1  class="fade">Whether youre in it for...</h1>
    <img class="fade" src="images/photos/food&drink2.jpg" alt="picture of artistic coffee being made">  
    <p class="fade">The food and drink,</p>
    <img class="fade" src="images/photos/work2.jpg" alt="picture of laptop at a coffee table">
    <p class="fade">Getting some work done,</p>
    <img class="fade" src="images/photos/people2.jpg" alt="picture of a couples hands holding coffee">
    <p class="fade">The people,</p>
    <img class="fade" src="images/photos/book2.jpg" alt="picture of a book and coffee">
    <p class="fade">Or a good book,</p>
    <h2 class="fade">We got you covered!</h2>
    </div>

    <img class="fade" src="images/awards.png" style="display: block; margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto; width: 460px;" alt="three award icons">
    <ul>
        <li class="fade">Sustainable high quality coffee</li>
        <li class="fade">Comfortable seating</li>
        <li class="fade">A variety of table layouts to suit your needs</li>
        <li class="fade">High speed internet </li>
        <li class="fade">Charging ports provided</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Here's a fiddle to play with:
https://jsfiddle.net/t4Ljnk7v/1/

I updated the `pageBottom` variable so you can see the bottom elements fade in when you get to the bottom.

Comment: ah yes it works thanks so much. I didn't realise I cut out the transition property, silly.